# Renaming columns based on condition in Pandas with lstrip is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2020-08-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01'], 'd1_ads' : [3, 5, 6],'d7_ads' : [8, 9, 15], 'd30_ads' : [12, 10, 22]})
```

And I want to remove the first letter d from the columns d1_ads, d7_ads and d30_ads. The first column date should remain like that, with the letter d. I have tried this code to achieve this:

```
df2.iloc[:,1:3].columns.str.lstrip("d")
```

And this is what I get:

```
Index(['1_iap', '7_iap', '30_iap',],
      dtype='object')
```

But when I try to save it on the dataframe, it is not working:

```
df2.iloc[:,1:3].columns = df2.iloc[:,1:3].columns.str.lstrip("d")
```

And my columns remain the same:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2020-08-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01'], 'd1_ads' : [3, 5, 6],'d7_ads' : [8, 9, 15], 'd30_ads' : [12, 10, 22]})
```

This would be the expected output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2020-08-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01'], '1_ads' : [3, 5, 6],'7_ads' : [8, 9, 15], '30_ads' : [12, 10, 22]})
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems it is not saving the changes correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use df.rename(...) to rename columns. You'll have to create a dict which maps the name: {'old': 'new'}

```py
df2.rename(columns={i: i.lstrip("d") for i in df2.iloc[:,1:4].columns},
           inplace=True)
# print(df2.to_markdown())
```

|  | date | 1_ads | 7_ads | 30_ads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-08-01 | 3 | 8 | 12 |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 | 5 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 | 6 | 15 | 22 |

Comment: Thanks! I was using rename but writing each column separately in the dict. Didn't think about it this way. It's been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `lstrip` the last three column names then add the first column name or with `.str.replace`

```py
df2.columns = df2.columns[:1].tolist() + df2.columns[1:].str.lstrip("d").tolist()
# or
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('^d(\d.*)', r'\1', regex=True)
```